# How to disable selection of some records based on a column value in Angular UI Grid?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using Angular UI Grid with enableRowHeaderSelection value as true. This allows user to select rows by clicking on the check box.

Is there a way to disable the row selection for certain rows based on a column value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what you're looking for: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/210_selection

Working Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vJbvJhgyKbYomW4VIsKs?p=preview

> You can use an `isRowSelectable` function to determine which rows are selectable. If you set this function in the options after grid initialisation you need to call `gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.OPTIONS)` to enable the option.

```
$scope.gridOptions.isRowSelectable = function(row) {
    if(row.entity.name === "Jack") return false;
    else return true;
}
$scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.OPTIONS);
```

Comment: I tried this and it's not working for me. I put this code in a method and calling after set the data to the grid. Is that the right way to do?

Comment: @vthallam See this working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/vJbvJhgyKbYomW4VIsKs?p=preview  Put the method right into the `$scope.gridOptions` definition.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Can you please edit the answer and add that plunkr link. Thank you!